# filter dropdown in sqlform,'Query' object is not callable

Tags: mysql, web2py

I want to insert a form include two fields:coursename,teacher_id(reference auth_user),but the teacher_id field show all the id in auth_user,I only want the user's id whoes role=teacher to show in the dropdown.as all the users are in the same table(auth_user)
this is what i have done:but it show the error:'Query' object is not callable.

```
query=(db.auth_membership.user_id==db.auth_user.id)(db.auth_membership.group_id==db.auth_group.id)(db.auth_group.role=='teacher')
db.courses.teacher_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db(query),'auth_user.id')
form=SQLFORM(db.courses)
return dict(form=form)
```

Thanks
jian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query=(db.auth_membership.user_id==db.auth_user.id)(db.auth_membership.group_id==db.auth_group.id)(db.auth_group.role=='teacher')
```

The above is not valid syntax. A Set object is callable, and when called, it returns another Set object, so you can chain Sets:

```
myset = db(query1)(query2)(query3)
```

If you instead want to work with Query objects, you have to make explicit conjunctions using the "&" operator:

```
myquery = query1 & query2 & query3
```

Comment: thank you Anthony. my problem is solved.the right query is that:query=(db.auth_membership.user_id==db.auth_user.id)&(db.auth_membership.group_id==db.auth_group.id)&(db.auth_group.role=='teacher')